# I get expect expression error in C for pset1 mario

Tags: c, cs50

Code:

```
int main(void)
{
printf("Height: ");
int height = 0;
height = get_int();
int heightcopy = height;
int spaces = heightcopy - 2;
int hash = 2;


while(height > 0 || height < 23)
    {
        for(int a = 0;a < height;a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0;b < spaces;b++)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            for(int c = 0;c < hash;c++)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            hash++;
            heightcopy--;
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

make MarioEasy_2
clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    MarioEasy_2.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o MarioEasy_2

this is the new error

........................................

Comment: The first `while` loop makes no sense. It's an infinite loop because you never change `height` inside the loop. I think you mean to use `if`.

Comment: You really need to go back to the books and learn how `if`, `while`, and `for` work. You don't understand the basics.

Comment: SO is not a programming school, it's not supposed to be a substitute for learning the language.

Comment: You also need to explain what this program is supposed to be doing. What's the purpose of the `a`, `b`, and `c` variables.

Comment: What's the point of `if(hash == 1)`? Nothing ever changes the value of `hash`, so this will always be true.

Comment: And since `hash` is `1`, the `c` loop will always execute just 1 time, so why have a loop there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to explain what is supposed to come out of this program to get proper feedback on any logical errors.

Syntactically speaking:

`spaces` needs to be initialized after you get a value for `height`

the

`while(int letter; letter < param; letter++)`

should be

`int letter;`

`for(letter=0; letter < param; letter++)`

C code doesn't like the int declaration in the for loop (C++ is cool with it)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that he was using C11.  The suggestion I made isn't less safe and you might be surprised how many compilers don't default to C99+ :)

Comment: Yes, I assume that most people are using a version of the language less than 2 decades old.

Comment: it works now but the || bollian expresion dosent work

Comment: Barmar?  No?  Well try `if ((height > 0) || (height < 23))`

Answer (score 0):

You have used a while loop here: `while(int a;a < height;a++)` but that is not the format of a `while` statement. A `while` statement will only take a single Boolean expression, as you have done previously in `while(height > 0 || height < 23)`. You need the `for` loop instead, and you also need to initialize the `int` you use with a number eg. `int a = 0`:

```
for(int a = 0;a < height;a++)
```

This is true of your other `while` loops below this as well.

Comment: thanks i also do all of your sugeestion but it wont run itbut it also wont give me errors

Comment: clang -fsanitize=integer -fsanitize=undefined -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wshadow    MarioEasy_2.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o MarioEasy_2

Comment: can any of you make sense of that

Comment: @FantasticMrFox It's declared in the loop, but it's not initialized.